# Php code not working in page but in phpdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know this is similar question but the query varies...

I have a query which is working in PHP admin but not on the PHP page:

```
$sql = "select sess_id 
    from info
   group by sess_id
  having count(*) > 1";
```

and the php code is as follows:

```
$sql = "select sess_id 
    from info
   group by sess_id
  having count(*) > 1";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    echo "New record1 created successfully";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

The other queries in this PHP code does work but not this particular query...

Please help me out.

Comment: Did any error appeared?

Comment: what ur getting when executing this query

Comment: What MySQL library you use? Because you issue a query that returns data, most probably `$conn->query($sql)` returns a resultset (encapsulated in an object) on success (and `FALSE` on failure). You should check `if ($conn->query($sql) !== FALSE)` but the success message you display is misleading as the query doesn't create any record.

Comment: If your query works on your admin panel, but not from a web page, there's probably a problem with the connection between them, please share your connect string.

Comment: *"Php code not working in page but in phpdmin"* -- `phpMyAdmin` is a MySQL client; it doesn't run your PHP code. The title is misleading and `phpMyAdmin` is not related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

why are you saying if 
    ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
try making two ='s.

Comment: If you think this is the solution then explain why it is wrong as it is and why your suggestion will fix it.